# How to perform segue from a didSelectRowAt

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am stuck with this simple task to perform segue from a selected cell.

I've created a segue from one ViewController to another with an identifier "showDetails". Than I try this code:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetails", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetails",
    let destination = segue.destination as? DetailsViewController {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        destination.rideIndex = indexPath.row
    }
}
```

Apparently it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check it once in the storyboard, the name of segue is "showDetails" same with a proper case?

Comment: What error do you get on the console?

Comment: yes, it is the same

Comment: the issue can be in `segue.destination as? DetailsViewController` check. Open the storyboard and check the destination controller class. Also always try to use breakpoints.

Comment: What doesn't work? Is `didSelectRowAt` called? Is `prepare(for segue` called? Is the check `destination as? DetailsViewController`passed? You should force unwrap `as! DetailsViewController`. It reveals immediately the **design** mistake if there is one. And rather then retrieving the index path explicitly pass it as `sender` parameter when calling `performSegue`

Comment: I've forgotten to call `tableView.delegate = self` in viewDidLoad.  Now everything works just fine. Sorry for the question

Answer (score 1):

Check the UITableView delegate and be sure that you are setting your segue to "Present Modally or show" and :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetails" {
        let destination = segue.destination as! DetailsViewController 
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        destination.rideIndex = indexPath.row
    }
}
```

But personally I prefer the below code to open an UIViewController:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let destination = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailsViewController") as! DetailsViewController
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        destination.rideIndex = indexPath.row
        self.present(destination, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and make sure that your DetailsViewController have an identifier "DetailsViewController"